# Swift returning NULL in guard statement

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

I have been working on this bug for about 8 hours now.

Into the function mapJsonToRest I am passing in a JSON object (I have verified it is working inside the function up until the guard let rest statement) and a String. From what I understand the String is trivial, currently "id" is being passed into the function.

From here things gets wonky. This statement is returning out of the function ( I am guessing because it is null.)

```
guard let rest = object[restKey] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return mappedRest }
```

However I have no idea why it would be doing this. It seems that restKey is null which is causing the else to return. I would appreciate any help because my poor head doesn't have much hair left to pull out.

If it helps, the tutorial I have been following was done in Swift 3 and I am writing this in Swift 5.

```
import Foundation

class RestDataParser {

static func mapJsonToRest(object: [String: AnyObject], restKey: String) -> [Restaurant] {
    var mappedRest: [Restaurant] = []
    
    //This is the humdinger right here
    guard let rest = object[restKey] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return mappedRest }
        
         for resting in rest {
            guard let id = resting["id"] as? String,
                  let name = resting["name"] as? String,
                  let rating = resting["rating"] as? String,
                  let location = resting["address1"] as? String,
                  let imageURL = resting["image_url"] as? String else { continue }

            print("By George, I think we've got it.")

            let restClass = Restaurant(id: id, name: name, rating: rating, location: location, imageURL: imageURL)
            mappedRest.append(restClass)

    }
    return mappedRest
}

}
```

Comment: Debug your code. Print `object`. Does it have the key represented by `restKey`? If yes, is  `rest` an array? If yes, are all types in the `guard` statement the expected types? By the way the tutorial seems to be even older. Since Swift 3 the unspecified type in a JSON object is `Any`, not `AnyObject`. And as you are talking about Swift 5 it's highly recommended to parse the JSON with `Decodable`.

Comment: I can print object, which returns an array. Maybe this is where I am having issues. What key should I be returning? Or how do I figure that out? Is it something in the JSON object?

Comment: The tutorial is about 4 years old.

Comment: In terms of Swift four years are ages. `object` cannot be an array otherwise the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: For sake of our monitor space I won't paste the whole thing. This is what object is printing right before the guard let. ["businesses": <__NSArrayI 0x6000032f9550>(
{
    alias =  ....     };
}, "total": 554]. Maybe it is a Dictionary and not an array?

Comment: `object` is a dictionary and `restKey` must be `businesses`.

Comment: SMH....You are right. I tried everything under Valhalla in that pesky id. Just to make sure I learned something. The reason it is businesses, is because it is that is the first object in the array?

Comment: If you don't post your decoding approach including the data received we can only guess. print the json data received `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)` and add it to your question.

Comment: Once again `object` is **not** an array.

Comment: If you want to insist in manually parsing your object try casting to `[String: [[String: Any]]]`

Comment: "The reason it is businesses, is because it is that is the first object in the array?" **No.** An array would have only commas, no semicolon. So `["this", "is", "an", "array"]`, but `["this": "is", "a": "dictionary"]`. A dictionary contains a list of key-value pairs: `[key1: value1, key2: value2, ... etc.]` So "business" is the first *key* in the dictionary. (I don't think it's the only one, "total" seems to be the last key, but it's not clear how much you skipped.) It's a key, but its value needs to be an array of dictionaries in order to comply with the `guard`...